# CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy annotation always generate unique constraint Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot

I used Spring boot version 3.1.x. It always generate unique constraint in the database when the table first creation using Jpa.

```
  @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", nullable = true)
    var createdBy: User? = null

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedBy
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by", nullable = true)
    var updatedBy: User? = null
```

[image: The result in database]

On Spring boot version 2.x.x it' working fine.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I would say that is kind of expected for `@OneToOne` association. Are you sure you didn't mean `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey B. Panfilov due to the wrong association.